# iOS Push notifications with a .p8 key not working from Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

APNs authentication key (.p8)

I have tried sending to only iOS devices from the firebase console and also by topic however nothing is getting to the device.  I have used p12 successfully in the past.

I have added the GoogleService-Info.plist file to the app and deployed to the App Store.
I am using @capacitor-community/fcm in the App and have followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm#certificate

I am testing in production as it didn’t work in dev with a provisioning profile.
Everything works ok for Android.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

UPDATE:
I have also tried following the instructions here however the code errors in Xcode at Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken:
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase#add-initialization-code

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following this guide:
https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-capacitor/

There are some differences in the Podfile and AppDelegate.swift otherwise it is pretty much the same.